# Como comprobar existencia de registros en mysql con php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo un trabajo para clase en el que me piden que haga un sistema de registros, que inserte los datos del usuario en una base de datos, tengo la siguiente función:

```
function comprovaUsuari($user, $passwd){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $dbpasswd = "";

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=php",$username, $dbpasswd);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'";
    $rows = $conn->query($sql);
    $rows = $rows -> fetch();

    return $CORRECTE = ($rows==0);
}
```

Esto ha sido lo último que he probado, después, tengo un condicional, conforme si la variable CORRECTE es true, me dirá error, pero de lo contrario, me insertará los registros en la tabla:

```
$CORRECTE = comprovaUsuari($user, $pass);

if ($CORRECTE){
    setcookie("error", "Nom d'usuari ja ocupat, torna a intentar", time() + 2, "/");
    header("Location: register.php");

}else{
    afegirUsuari($user, $name, $pass);
}
```

El principal problema que tengo es que llevo un par de días probando, pero cambiando todo tipo de condiciones, simplemente tengo dos opciones, o me deja introducir infinitamente el mismo usuario, o no me deja introducir ninguno, cuando la idea es que solo pueda introducir una sola vez "x" nombre de usuario, a ver si alguien puede alumbrarme un poco.

Por cierto, los campos de la tabla users son name, username, password y ID

Comment: Fíjate que `$CORRECTE` está en True cuando `rows == 0`, es decir cuando no hay ningún registro. Luego dices que si no es `$CORRECTE`, que añada. O sea que solo permites que añada si ya hay un registro. Es cuestión de poner un nombre más representativo a la variable, que si no es lioso :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes 2 opciones para la comprobación de datos:

**Comprobar que las filas que devuelve esté vacía, entonces insertamos el usuario**

```
function comprovaUsuari($user, $passwd){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $dbpasswd = "";

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=php",$username, $dbpasswd);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $CORRECTE = false;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'";
    $rows = $conn->query($sql);
    $rows = $rows->fetch();

    if(!rows){
        $CORRECTE = true;
    }

    return $CORRECTE;
}
```

**Comprobar que las columnas que devuelve sea igual a 0, entonces insertamos el usuario**

```
function comprovaUsuari($user, $passwd){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $dbpasswd = "";

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=php",$username, $dbpasswd);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $CORRECTE = false;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'";
    $rows = $conn->query($sql);

    if($rows->columnCount() === 0){
        $CORRECTE = true;
    }

    return $CORRECTE;
}
```

Comment: Puedes simplificar `if($rows->columnCount() === 0) ....` por `return $rows->columnCount() === 0` si deseas.

Answer (score 4):

Ya que no devuelves todas las columnas de la tabla users, has un Count y obtienes únicamente este valor. Tu función quedaría de la siguiente manera:

> Modificado para mejorar la seguridad en la consulta gracias a A. Cedano.

```php
function comprovaUsuari($user, $passwd){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $dbpasswd = "";

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=php",$username, $dbpasswd);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = :user";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':user' => $user));
    $result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    return ($result==0);
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta a mi juicio es la mejor, debería ser la respuesta aceptada, pues nada mejor que `COUNT` para verificar si un registro existe. Para ser perfecta le faltarían dos cosas: 1. Usar `fetchColumn` en vez de `fetchObject` y 2. aplicar consultas preparadas, pues el código actualmente adolece de un grave problema de seguridad. No cuesta nada corregir eso , mucho más si se está usando PDO. Tendrás mi +1 si corriges eso.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un par de cosas que, igual por ignorancia mia, no veo del todo claras en tu código.

La primera es la forma de obtener el número de registros. Si realmente lo unico que quieres es obtener el numero de registros que cumplent una condición te sugiero que hagas un `COUNT()` en tu consulta sql y luego acceder al valor devuelto por la consulta.

En segundo lugar, y suponiendo que quieres mantener la consulta sql, no tengo nada claro que esto sea correcto:

```
$rows = $rows -> fetch();
$rows == 0; //$rows no debe ser un número, en todo caso será un array
            //por lo que deberias hacer un count
```

En tercer lugar no tengo claro tampoco que esta sentencia sea correcta:

```
return $CORRECTE = ($rows==0);
```

Ya que esa sintaxis es confusa, debería ser del estilo `return (/*Expresión bool*/);` ya que aunque funcionase correctamente no sigue una buena sintaxis.